# DORA between a client and unknown DHCP server

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, dhcp

I have an isc-dhcp-server installed on an Ubuntu VM that has 2 interfaces connected to VM Client1 Centos & VM Client2 Ubuntu. There are 3 networks: Client1 & DHCP, Client2 & DHCP, and Client1 & Client2.

[Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO5NI.jpg)

How come I have DORA between the clients and IP x.x.x.3 DHCP server instead of x.x.x.254 IP's that are assigned static to DHCP server interfaces that are also default gateway IP's.

UPD: I am still able to get an IP from this IP x.x.x.3 DHCP server even if the main x.x.x.254 IP DHCP is down.

Comment: perhaps don't use acronyms that some might not know.  what's "DORA"?  (for those who don't know how DHCP works)

Comment: DHCP session: DISCOVER - OFFER - REQUEST - ACKNOWLEDGE

Comment: It looks like now each client has its own DHCP server running from which it gets its IP. `ip n` shows it as "dev enp0s3 lladdr".

Comment: Did you check each system to make sure it doesn't have a DHCP server configured/installed on them?  The behavior you're expecting here sounds like each system has its own DHCP server.  You should only have *one* DHCP network for the entire environment, or ignore DHCP and static-IP your systems.  Having multiple DHCP servers and interconnectivity like this without proper firewalling/relaying/etc. setups can result in this breakage.  (also I know what DORA is, but others might not :P)

Comment: Thomas thanks! Sorry didn't take this into account someone might mot know but probably he/she could not help in this case.

The problem is I did not install any DHCP server on the virtual machines so such a behavior looks strange to me. Do not have any clue where the x.x.x.3 DHCP comes from and how to locate it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Changed Net1 & Net2 (see the picture) to y.y1.y.0/24 and y.y2.y.0/24 accordingly and now the clients get their IP's as usual however this 'ghost' DHCP server still keeps offering its network IP's. Maybe it's the kernel issue that had arisen when I first tried setting up the DHCP server.

Comment: start by going to your sysotem and running `sudo dhclient -4 -v` and give us the output?  That will help you ID which server/sstem is reporting to you with the offer.  That'll allow you to track a little bit *where* your DHCP is being ahndled by.

Comment: Thanks! It might have helped but I've already rearranged everything. I suppose the problem could have occurred because I previously set up NAT Networks with the same IP's and connected the VM's to them. Then I re-linked them with Internal Networks.